# Best practice - exception handling

Tags: java, performance, exception

I don't know what are the best practices in my case :

1:

```
public class garage {

    private List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Cars>();

    public String getCarSeatSomething(String carName, String brandName) {
           for(Car car : cars){
              if(car.getName().equals(carName)){
                 Seats seats = car.getSeats();
                 List<Brand> brands = seats.getBrands();
                 for(Brand brand: brands ){
                    if(brand.getName().equals(brandName)){
                       return brand.something();
                    }
                 }
              }
           }
           return null;
     }
         ...
}
```

I have many method like this, so I will have some redundant code with this solution.

Moreover, in my program, it's not "normal" that we don't find the car, so I think I have to use Exception no ?

2 :

```
public class Garage {

    private List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();

    public Something getCarSeatSomething(String carName, String brandName) {
           Car car = searchCar(carName);
           if(car == null) 
              return null;
           else{
              Seats seats = car.getSeats();
              return seats.getSomething(brandName);
           }  
    } 
        ...
}


public class Seats {

    private List<Brand> brands = new ArrayList<Brand>(); 

    protected Something getSomething(brandName){
              Brand brand = searchBrand(brandName);
              if(brand == null)
                 return null;
              else
                 return brand.something();
    }
      ...
}
```

Less redundant code and less code for each method of the class Garage because the search are only in searchBrand and searchCar.
But I have allways the problem of exceptions.

So, my last solution, is to throw exception in the searchBrand and searchCar methods, add throws at all the methods (like getCarSeatSomething) which use searchBrand/searchCar and try ... catch when I use these methods (like getCarSeatSomething).

Is that correct ?
If not, have you got better ideas ?

Comment: Write code to use values - and avoid exceptions, except when something exceptional (and often not recoverable at the immediate level) occurs. Basically, ask these: what happens when a request is *not* able to be fulfilled? who's fault is it? what is expected to be done about it?

Comment: If I don't find a car for example, I have to log it. It's the fault of the caller, not of the object which contains cars.

Comment: "avoid **exceptions**, **except** when something **exceptional** occurs" -- awesome :-)

Comment: If the caller is expected to provide a name that exists, you should throw an exception if the name isn't found.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like car name and brand name will be user provided input. In that case, you should expect users to provide names that do not exist. It is not exceptional. Return `null` and in the top layer, return an error message to the user. It seems reasonable that you might try to "get" something and not get it at all. `null` is appropriate here. But make sure you are consistent about this behavior across your application and you document it.

Answer (score 0):

To describe the situation: you have a elaborate data hierarchy, with possibly a chained access:

```
x.getLiat().get(3).getAs().lookupB("a1").getC();
```

This may lead to a design with either expectable NullPointerExceptions to be handled (ugly) or Excptions.

**Java 8** proposes [`Optional<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) to explicitly handle in one expression what otherwise could be a null.

```
x.getA().orElse(a).getB().orElseThrow(() -> new XException()).getC();
```

Better yet is to use java 8's streams, with filtering, mapping, find any/first capabilities.

```
private List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();

public Optional<String> getCarSeatSomething(String carName, String brandName) {
    return cars.stream()
        .filter((car) -> car.getName().equals(carName))
        .flatMap{(car) -> car.getSeats())
        .flatMap((seats) -> seats.getBrands())
        .filter((brand) -> brand.getName().equals(brandName))
        .findFirst();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If an entity must contain a particular attribute then getter methods for that attribute should throw an exception if the entity cannot provide the attribute.

If it is *optional* for an entity to contain the attribute, then getter methods should not throw an exception.

Some scenarios will involve both cases, where in some contexts access to the attribute is mandatory and in other contexts it is optional.  Then you should provide two "getter" methods, one that will throw an exception if the attribute cannot be returned, and the other an Optional value.  I recommend using the method naming convention of *getEntity* for mandatory getter methods and *findEntity* for optional getter methods.

In the case where an entity must contain a particular attribute and the getter method cannot complete the request, you have a malformed entity.  If your entity is throwing exceptions because it cannot return mandatory attributes you have a bug or problems with how you created the entity.

Entities should never be created without mandatory attributes.  Constructors and factories should enforce mandatory attributes.  For entities that must be created and not fully formed (like Data Access Objects) separate validation should be applied to the entities before being used.  Or separate your domain entity and DAO into separate but equivalent types.